# CSS Modules: selecting child class through selectors

Tags: css, postcss, css-modules

So,

I have appended a home class to body like so:

```
 document.body.classList.add("home")
```

I want to select appContainer a child element of body class by doing

```
html body.home #appContainer { ..... }
```

This works without CSS Modules but was wondering how I can do it with CSS modules. Thanks

Comment: can't you just define the css module with a specific name that you look for in the components you want to use it in? like for instance `className={myModules[this.someKey]}`

Comment: html body:global(.home) #appContainer ?

Comment: @AdamWolski Perfect! Thank you verymuch

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to use wrap the class that you want to be global into `:global()`. If your selector uses an element you must write it directly after the element with no space in between, like `element:global(.class)` which translates into `element.class`.

Therefore, in your case `html body:global(.home) #appContainer` is the answer.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else that comes across this issue, I am using [postcss-preset-env](https://preset-env.cssdb.org/) and I had to do this:

Worked ✅

```css
.toolTipTest :global .rc-tooltip-arrow {
  color: blue;
}
```

This did not work ❌

```css
.toolTipTest:global(.rc-tooltip-arrow) {
  color: blue;
}
```

And neither did this ❌

```
.toolTipTest:global(.rc-tooltip-arrow) {
  color: blue;
}
// Neither Did this
.toolTipTest {
  &:global(.rc-tooltip-arrow) {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```